# Error C2248: 'boost::asio::basic_io_object<IoObjectService>::basic_io_object' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::asio::basic_io

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

This class is giving me a C2248 Error. It thinks im trying to access a private member declared in Boost Basic_io_object class.
The error appears to be occurring in the initializer list because it compiles when I comment it out.
Does anyone have any ideas please?

```
class session
: public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
 public:
 session(tcp::socket& socket)
 : socket_(std::move(socket))
 {
 }

 ~session()
 {
     std::cout << "session ended" << std::endl;
 }

 void start()
 {
     std::cout << "session started" << std::endl;
     do_read();
 }

 private:
 void do_read()
 {
     auto self(shared_from_this());
     socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
     [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_write(length);
          }
        });
  }

  void do_write(std::size_t length)
  {
      auto self(shared_from_this());
      boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t )
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
              do_read();
          }
        });
  } 

  tcp::socket socket_;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length]; 
};
```

Comment: Are you copying your `session` class somewhere?

Comment: No worries I've found the issue. Changing the private socket_ member to a reference fixed it

Comment: @StevenTurner please add an answer

Answer (score -1):

change `tcp::socket socket_` to `tcp::socket& socket_` is ok